# Node.js - Download file after asynchronous functions are done

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

I have got a reverse proxy and a node.js server which sends a plain/text response back to the proxy which, in turn, does a bunch of front-end stuff 0% related to my problem.

The plain/text response comes from multiple asynchronous functions and the user is informed of the progress as each async function completes through the usage of

> res.write("Example");

The problem is, the node.js server is supposed to prompt the browser for a download after all the async functions are complete. It's irrelevant how or where the file is downloaded.

I have tried to set the headers to `Content-Disposition: attachment`, but Node just throws something like `Error: Can't set headers after they are sent`.

Here's a code example:

```
app.post('/', function(req, res) {
    res.statusCode = 200;
    /*
    Bunch of async functions
    */
    res.download("some_file"); // This is included in the callback after all async functions are done
});

app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log('The server is running at http://whatever:3000/');
});
```

The async functions make use of `eachSeries` from the `async` module. This is another example of what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
async.eachSeries(func1,func2,function(err){
    // something to prompt the user for download
});
```

Do I have to create another instance of express just to serve the download or is there some way to do everything within one express() instance?

Comment: I don't think you can actually do this without some HTML redirect magic that sendsthe user to a different route which performs the actual download.

Comment: I agree with Darkhogg. File attachment headers have to be set before writing, and if you start writing out text, the browser won't be able to start a download afterwards because it won't know where the file starts. If you don't want to require any user interaction, I'd use AJAX or WebSockets for pulling the status and displaying the progress, and once the client gets a message saying it's done, do a JS redirect to the download location.